# What are all of the variables in outlook msg objects

Tags: python, outlook

Using this code I'm getting the emails in my inbox:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
namespace = outlook.Session
recipient = namespace.CreateRecipient("someshareemail@email.com")
inbox = outlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 6)
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    print message.SenderName
    print message.SenderEmailAddress
```

And I was wondering, is there a way to get the IP of the sender?

I tried using dir() to find what properties the object had, but no go:

```
['_ApplyTypes_', '_FlagAsMethod', '_LazyAddAttr_', '_NewEnum', '_Release_', '__AttrToID__', '__LazyMap__', '__call__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__getattr__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__int__', '__len__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__nonzero__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '_builtMethods_', '_enum_', '_find_dispatch_type_', '_get_good_object_', '_get_good_single_object_', '_lazydata_', '_make_method_', '_mapCachedItems_', '_oleobj_', '_olerepr_', '_print_details_', '_proc_', '_unicode_to_string_', '_username_', '_wrap_dispatch_']
```

Comment: Try `dir(message)` and find out!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that initially and I got some weird values:'( edited question to reflect results

Answer (score 3):

You can read the value of the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS_W property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.  Look for the X-Originating-IP header, which if it exists should contain the IP address of the sender.

Comment: so would it be message.PropertyAccessor? Because for whatever reasons this is just printing out the body of the email.

Comment: `message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")` should do the job,

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko ah! that did the job, I have no idea what actually happened in the background though,c could you elaborate?